# Printing out specific string that corresponds to a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Hello I've been learning pyhton for about 2 weeks using mobile apps but I figured forcing myself to create a project is helping me learn faster. Is there a script can I use to assign a number to a string so when that specific int is pressed, it prints out it's definition?

```
>>>>d = {1:"apple", 2:"peach", 3:"cherry"}
>>>>mylist = ["apple", 1, "peach", 2, "cherry", 3 ]
>>>>num = int(input())
>>>>If num == int in mylist:
>>>>print(str(num))
```

sorry if I put the code in wrong format, but that's what I currently have. I wanted to make the outcome of user input recognize the int and print it's value without having to write every single out come. Is that possible or do I have to write them all?

Comment: Make a list of strings and use the index of the list to call the different strings

Comment: You might want to check out how [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  Dictionaries are made exactly for that purpose.  Here's an example:

```py
dictionary = {1: 'my string', 'string': 'other'}
print(dictionary[1])
print(dictionary['string'])
```

That will output

```
my string
other
```

You can assign numbers based on that.  Read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for a better understanding.

Comment: is there a way to make the outcome of num = int(input()) be  the value instead of an integer when I print it?

Comment: Try `print(yourdict[int(input())])`.  That will get input from the user and print the associated value from `yourdict`.  Just make sure that value exists!